# LINQ Searching Only Allowing Equivalency

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to filter a set of records based on a sub-object's criteria.  This compiles ok

```
recordList = recordList.Where(r => r.Areas.Where(a => a.Area == "Z").Count() > 0);
```

but this doesn't

```
recordList = recordList.Where(r => r.Areas.Where(a => a.Area <= "Z").Count() > 0);
```

giving these errors
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type
Delegate 'System.Func' does not take '1' arguments
Operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

!= works ok, by any sort of less than or greater than operation fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has got nothing to do with LINQ not allowing the use of <=, but that strings cannot be compared with this operator (yet can obviously use equal or not equal).

Writing this in a console app:

```
string strA = "jamie";
string strB = "Z";
Console.WriteLine(strA != strB);
Console.WriteLine((bool)(strA <= strB));
```

Underlines the final line with (basically) the same error

> Cannot apply operator '<=' with type
>   'string' and 'string'

Now, you can use the <= operator on `char`, so the similar code below compiles and works as expected:

```
char charA = 'J';
char charB = 'Z';
Console.WriteLine(charA<=charB);
```

So maybe what you want is:

```
recordList = recordList.Where(r => r.Areas.Where(a => a.Area[0] <= 'Z').Count() > 0);
```

HTH.

Comment: Thanks folks - could have sworn I've done that with string elsewhere, which is why I asked the question, but maybe I haven't....
(Might be thinking of when I was doing this with the dynamic SQL class)

Comment: @Mad : T-SQL, VB classic, VB.NET all allow the use of `<` etc as operators on string values. It's C# that's different here.

Answer (score 1):

> Operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

Well there it is. To compare for ordering, rather than for equality, use `string.Compare`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do < and > on chars but not on strings ;) Use String.Compare or you can write your own comparer to compare 2 strings.